# Function return value to variable

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am having trouble assigning function return value to variable. Why do I get the function returned instead of the final product when I log it to console?

```
time = ->
  today = new Date()
  minutes = today.getMinutes()
  if minutes < 10 then minutes = "0#{minutes}"
  hours = today.getHours()
  if hours < 10 then hours = "0#{hours}"
  "#{hours}:#{minutes}"
console.log time
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add `do` to execute the function (if you expect "time" to contain the string, not the function):

```
time = do ->
```

or use "time" as a function, i.e., invoke it:

```
console.log time()
```